# Spark update dataframe with where condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes in Spark (PySpark)

```
DF_A
col1    col2    col3
a        1      100
b        2      300
c        3      500
d        4      700
```

```
DF_B
col1    col3
a       150
b       350
c       0
d       650
```

I want to update the columns of DF A with values DF_B.col3 wherever present.

Currently I am doing

```
df_new = df_a.join(df_b, df_a.col1 == df_b.col1,'inner')
```

And it is giving me col1 X 2 times and col3 X 2 times in df_new.
Now I have to drop the irrelevant cells to show 0. What is a better way of doing this? without using udfs.

Comment: What is the final result that you need. I'm not quite sure I understand that.

Comment: Its more like this sql statement : UPDATE table_a A, table_b B SET A.col3= B.col3 WHERE A.col1= B.col1; on the dataframe. If not present  in B then 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to perform the following operation :

*UPDATE table_a A, table_b B SET A.col3= B.col3 WHERE A.col1= B.col1; on the dataframe. If not present in B then 0*. (Cf. comments)

```
a = [("a",1,100),("b",2,300),("c",3,500),("d",4,700)]
b = [("a",150),("b",350),("d",650)]
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(a,["col1","col2","col3"])   
df_b = spark.createDataFrame(b,["col1","col3"])

df_a.show()
# +----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|
# +----+----+----+
# |   a|   1| 100|
# |   b|   2| 300|
# |   c|   3| 500|
# |   d|   4| 700|
# +----+----+----+

df_b.show() # I have removed an entry for the purpose of the demo.
# +----+----+
# |col1|col3|
# +----+----+
# |   a| 150|
# |   b| 350|
# |   d| 650|
# +----+----+
```

You'll need to perform an `outer join` followed by a `coalesce` :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_a.withColumnRenamed('col3','col3_a') \
    .join(df_b.withColumnRenamed('col3','col3_b'), on='col1', how='outer') \
    .withColumn("col3", F.coalesce('col3_b', F.lit(0))) \
    .drop(*['col3_a','col3_b']).show()
# +----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|
# +----+----+----+
# |   d|   4| 650|
# |   c|   3|   0|
# |   b|   2| 350|
# |   a|   1| 150|
# +----+----+----+
```